# tooltip jqueryUI css issue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have an issue about jqueryUI tooltip..

In fact, impossible to change the css style of the class .ul-tooltip. .
specially on firefox.

In more, even on the offical website.. On the demo : https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style

When I look the style on firefox and on chrome, the style are different.

I try to override the css

```
.ui-tooltip {
  background: #fcfcfa !important;
  color: #86c724 !important;
  border: 1px solid #86c724 !important;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px !important;
  padding: 10px !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px  rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
          box-shadow: 0 0 5px  rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
```

but no result.

I try to add a new class and manage style by it.. no result

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".infoboxcontainer" ).tooltip({
      tooltipClass: "myNewClass"
    });

  });
  </script>
```

No idea what happen.. it's like if firefox add is own css for tooltip.

Comment: have you included reset css ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpk0uxjL/ it seems to work fine for me

Comment: Are you also using bootstrap?

Comment: Thank's for your help, .. @Jacob I try your link.. but I get the same result : http://i62.tinypic.com/11twrkm.png

Comment: @Carlo - I have added the reset css, but no change.. -

Comment: @Ori No I include only Jquery and jqueryUI to my page

Comment: @Mike5 what browser version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Thank's for your help of all.

I found the solution.. it was from a Firefox extention.. When the Avast Online Security extention is enable, it create this issue and replace the css of the tooltip..

Answer (score 0):

Try including this css file before all other css :

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/